# Data validation - You can write only two times same value in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to do a validation to the schedule. I would like to be able to enter a certain number of times a given symbol in one column.

E.g. "T" can be entered 2 times in 2 different fields in a column, and "C1" only once in a column.

[image: How it looks]

Using `COUNTIF` I can limit what I can type in (e.g. T,C1,C2) but I don't know how to further limit what I can use.

Comment: Do you ask how to add all necessary conditions for validation at the same time?

Comment: " "T" can be entered 2 times" means T MUST be entered 2 times or maximum 2 times?

Comment: maximum 2 times. I have sth like this:
AND(COUNTIF(B$3:B$11;"T")<3;COUNTIF(B$3:B$11;"10")<2;COUNTIF(B$3:B$11;"C1")<2;COUNTIF(B$3:B$11;"C2")<2;COUNTIF(B$3:B$11;"12")<3;COUNTIF($A$13:$A$19;B3)>0)
I think it's working.